# Setting MySQL server to work remotely

Tags: c#, mysql

I am using MySQL, and XAMPP and a C# app that I made.
The app is about reading a line in the DB and inserting a line in that same table.
I am logging to the DB, using connection string. (code below)
I am using a user different from root.
Everything works fine cause I am on the same machine that the db is up, but if I want to use the app in another PC, I should change the server ip right?
So I am replacing 127.0.0.1 by my ip from [What is My IP](https://www.whatismyip.com/) 
And it doesnt work.

I am getting mySQLexception 1042 - "can't resolve the client IP address into a hostname"

**So, do I need to set up something more on C# app, do I need to set up something on mysql?**
**is there a config file that I should change in order to make the DB work outside my machine?**

Sorry I am bit of a noob about DBs.
**Lastly, is it possible to refer to me to a easy place where I can host my db, I mean, I just want to export my db from mysql, and put it somewhere and then change the ip for whatever the host provides, or would I need to change a lot my db/C# app to do that?
Thanks in advance for any kind of help!**

```
server = "127.0.0.1";
port = "3306";
database = "bugtest";
//uid = "root";

uid = "anotherPC1";
//password = "pass1";

string connectionString;
connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "PORT=" + port + ";" +  "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
```

Answer (score 1):

The site whatismyip.com provides you public internet IP, be sure that this is what you want to do and you are not working into LAN.

Assuming that this is what you want, you can add a configuration setting on to mysql server, disable hostname resolution by adding `skip-name-resolve` in the `[mysqld]` section of the config file.

Doing this, enforces mysql to work only with IPs